# Scala and Set parametrized type by Int

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am working on some function which take an element and return singleton class with this element, as shown below:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set =
  e => elem == e
```

but scala REPL signalize such problem:

```
scala>   def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set =
     |     e => elem == e
<console>:7: error: type Set takes type parameters
         def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set =
```

I have tried to add type of Set as Int, but it doesn't help

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] =
  e => elem == e
```

and

```
scala>   def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] =
     |     e => elem == e
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Boolean
 required: Set[Int]
           e => elem == e
```

Frankly speaking, I don't know where my mistake is laid and I am using 2.11.4 scala :)

Edit:

Similar problem I had for this line of code:

```
def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Boolean
 required: Set[Int]
       def union(s: Set[Int], t: Set[Int]): Set[Int] = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
```

this causes similar error.

Edit:

I forgot about

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

Comment: `Set[Int]` is a subtype of `Int=>Boolean`, so your intuition goes the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] = Set(elem)
```

This way you will call the `Set.apply` method creating a `Set` with the single element of `e`.

Your intuition was the other way around for `Int=>Boolean` and `Set[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a type parameter to make it generic

```
def singletonSet[A](a: => A): Set[A] = Set(a)
```

The `=>` avoids the argument element to be evaluated before putting it in the `Set`.

---

Incidentally, what you're trying to implement is exactly the `point` method of an `Applicative` typeclass.

[Here's](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0-M3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala#L22) the scalaz version of it.

Using scalaz, you can do something like

```
1.point[Option] // Some(1)
1.point[Set]    // Set(1) -- this requires scalaz-outlaws
1.point[List]   // List(1)
```

Please notice that since `Set` is not considered to be a proper `Applicative` (nor a `Functor`), the implementation for its `Applicative` instance is provided by the [scalaz-outlaws](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/outlaws/std/Set.scala) project.

Comment: Why did you use call-by-name the 'a' argument ?

Comment: You don't want lifting into a container to cause evaluation of the argument. Or if you want, just remove the =>

Answer (score 0):

Following is a comparison - thus return type is boolean

```
elem == e
```

What you want:

```
Set(elem)
```

So:

```
scala> def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] = Set(elem)
singletonSet: (elem: Int)Set[Int]
```